# display search result in table view in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

1. I've created a table view with search bar in my View Controller, but the table view doesn't show the search result.
2. This is how my code working. First i create an Array to hold data >> display the array data in table view >> using search bar to filter the table view.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.inventoryarray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"apple",@"samsung",@"HTC",@"LG",@"Sony",@"Motorola",@"Nexus",@"Asus" ,nil];
    self.searchresult =[[NSArray alloc]init];    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma table View methods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchresult count];
    } else {
        return [self.inventoryarray count];
    }
}    

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CellID";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchresult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.inventoryarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }    
    return cell;    
}

#pragma search methods

-(void) filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];    
    self.searchresult = [self.inventoryarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString  {    
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]] ;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget to `refesh` data on `table`

```
 -(void) filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:   (NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                            predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                            searchText];

    self.searchresult = [self.inventoryarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    // you forget to reload Data
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    // else use 

    [yourtableView reloadData];
}
```

suggestion : `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated, use `UISearchController` on onwards, for [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to only `[tableView reloadData];` in last of `filterContentForSearchText` method.

if you wan't to use UISearchController then...
 - 'UISearchDisplayController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - UISearchDisplayController has been replaced with UISearchController

if you don't want to use `UISearchController` then use below method:

`- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {}` and reload tableview.